# Next.JS Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components

Tags: next.js, error-handling, tsx

I'm trying to fetch data inside app/facebook/page.tsx file but it won't let me. I've watched video on youtube ([*this one*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Sj05H2AuW8)) and it won't work.

I'm new to NextJS so please help if you know what I did wrong.

Error:

```
 ⨯ Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server".
  [function]
   ^^^^^^^^
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
 ⨯ Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server".
  [function]
   ^^^^^^^^
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "340599244"
```

app/facebook/page.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar';
import getPages from '../scripts/facebook-getPages';

export default async function Facebook() {
  const pages = await getPages();
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <div className='flex flex-col gap-2'>
        <h1 className='text-4xl font-bold'>Facebook</h1>
        <div className='w-full h-max bg-gradient-to-b from-neutral-900 to-neutral-800 border border-neutral-800 rounded-lg p-2'>
          <h3 className='font-medium text-xl'>Page list</h3>
          <div className='w-full rounded-lg bg-neutral-800 border border-neutral-700 mt-2 box-border px-3'>
            <table className='table-auto w-full'>
              <thead className='text-left border-b border-white/20'>
                <tr>
                  <th>Page name</th>
                  <th>Members</th>
                  <th>Token</th>
                  <th>Expiers</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

                {pages.map((page: any) => () => {
                  return (
                    <tr className='h-[50px] font-semibold border-b border-neutral-700'>
                      <td>
                        <div className='w-full flex items-center gap-2'>
                          <img src={page.picture} alt="" className='w-[40px] h-[40px] object-cover rounded-lg' />
                          <span>{page.name}</span>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>{page.members}</td>
                      <td>
                        <div className='flex gap-3 items-center'>
                          <div className='transition-all duration-500 cursor-pointer h-7 w-7 border border-neutral-700 hover:text-neutral-700 hover:bg-white hover:border-white rounded-md flex justify-center items-center'>
                            <i className="fa-solid fa-key"></i>
                          </div>
                          <span>{page.token}</span>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <span className='text-green-400'>{page.expires}</span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  )
                })}
              </tbody>
            </table>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

script where getPages is located:

```
export default async function getPages() {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3232/facebook/pages");

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }

    return await response.json();
}
```

I've done everything like guy in video and it won't work.